# using window.location to find the current URL

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fetch the current URL of the page I am on, I am using the following code for this, which is showing correctly in console.log..

I am trying to use that variable in jquery `find()` to find if certain exists in that url, do not execute the code.

Here is my try:

```
var $hostname = window.location.href;

if(($hostname).find('vpictures')) {/* Do nothing */}
    else {
        var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(oTable);
        $(tt.fnContainer()).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper'); 
    }
```

For running this, I am getting this Error:

```
TypeError: $hostname.find is not a function


if(($hostname).find('vpictures')) {/* Do nothing */}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting existing word you can simply use

```
if($hostname.indexOf('vpictures') > -1){
   //your script
}
```